# Creating structural parity between two tables in different databases using SQL only

Tags: sqlite

I've got two databases each containing a table of the same name and (at the outset) they're  structurally identical.  They exist independently of one another and can be dynamically modified during use such that over time either or both will have additional columns.  All columns are of text type.  To enable data exchange between the two tables I need to bring their structure in line periodically.

Understanding what columns are present in one but not the other is simple:

```
ATTACH DATABASE '/tmp/master.db' AS master;
ATTACH DATABASE '/tmp/slave.db' AS slave;

/* columns in slave not present in master */
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT name
      FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO('table', 'master') 
)
SELECT name
  FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO('table', 'slave') 
 WHERE name NOT IN cte;


/* columns in master not present in slave */
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT name
      FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO('table', 'slave') 
)
SELECT name
  FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO('table', 'master') 
 WHERE name NOT IN cte;
```

Going one step further one could write these column names to a table in each database by extending the above queries:

```
CREATE TABLE master.columns_to_add AS
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT name
      FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO('table', 'master')
)
SELECT name
  FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO('table', 'slave')
 WHERE name NOT IN cte;


CREATE TABLE slave.columns_to_add AS
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT name
      FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO('table', 'slave')
)
SELECT name
  FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO('table', 'master')
 WHERE name NOT IN cte;
```

Ultimately what I'd like to do is to be able to use the results of these queries to issue the appropriate statement:

```
ALTER TABLE database.table ADD COLUMN colum_name text
```

Easy enough to do with Python in the mix, but is there a way to do it purely via SQL?